# Where did I see characters sitting in window openings, behind (decrepit) Jumbotrons?

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyberpunk

In answering a related question on the English Language Stack, I had vivid memories of seeing movie scenes that pictured noir or cyberpunkesque* characters, lounging in window openings (open or missing the pane) of run down rooms, situated behind the rusting trusses of ((mal-)functioning) Jumbotrons.

I cannot give a better date-range than 1980-2010.

I couldn't remember any concrete examples of these works, despite seeming to remember more than one movie (at least two live action and one animated) featuring this.

Specifically, I am looking for one of the live-action ones: a female character in a long leather coat squats in the window-opening, directly outside the window are the trusses of a giant lighted display (jumbotron or billboard or huge neon sign). Reflections of neon can be seen, and we can gather that the room is completely derelict. Sadly I have not even vestiges of plot to go with that visual image.

*like the daywalker in Blade -i.e. not necessarily a character in a cyperpunk movie, but with some of the same fashion choices.

Comment: When you say "scenes" and "more than one instance" are you talking about multiple works, or just multiple scenes in a single work?  Live action or animated?  When and where did you see this?  Why/how were the characters "cyberpunkesque?"

Comment: @DavidW both live-action and animated - i worked it into the Q now   ---- Could the close-voters air their grievance, so i can react?

Comment: It's still not very clear if the move was live-action or animated. You say you remember two live-action and one animated, which one are you looking for?

Comment: @fez ... i am looking for three movies, one animated, two live action, all featuring characters in the described scenery

Comment: If they're three seperate and distinct movies then you'll have to ask three seperate and distinct questions I'm afraid

Comment: @fez got it. Focussed on one of them.

Comment: Could this be Aeon Flux? The time range is right, it was a cartoon and made into a live action movie, future dystopia and shots of her in front of decrepit buildings. If I recall her full suit had a long jacket?

Comment: How do you know it's a "jumbotron" as opposed to the skeleton of a plain old billboard or a neon sign?  (Like in [*Highlander*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxkm32jhdjw), for instance.)

Comment: You're describing the opening scene of the musical *'Rent'*

Comment: Blade runner? Johnny Mnemonic?

Comment: @DavidW - Sorry, i was not aware that there is a difference between the various lighted giant displays, will amend the Q

Comment: @Villan - Do you have a specific scene in mind (timecode)?

Comment: @bukwyrm no, it was just the first thing that came to mind upon reading the question, another possibility may be Ultraviolet, since it too was an anime movie made into a live action film.